# Adding link to customer account menu for selected users

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, navigation, link

I got this code, and that works well:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink"><name>someName</name><path>somePath</path><label>Some Label</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

But I just want to add this customer account navigation link for specific customers. I would be able to write some PHP what acquires the information if the user should view the custom navigation link, but i cannot do this with XML.

What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `app\design\frontend\PACKAGE\THEME\template\customer\account\navigation.phtml` to your theme. Then do changes according to this :

```
<div class="block block-account">

    ... 

    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>

            <?php
            if(true)//YOUR LOGIC FOR specific customers
            {
                //change values according to your requirements
                $this->addLink("Some Name", "MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION", "Some Label", array("PARAMETER"=>"VALUE"));
            }
            ?>

            <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
            <?php $_index = 1; ?>

            ...

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Yes, remove your XML code**

Comment: That's great! But what is, if I want to write an extension and I don't want to overwrite any files, including files in base directory?

Comment: In this solution, I've not overwritten any core files, we are just using template. I have just called `addLink` method of `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` block manually which `Magento` does internally while rendering layout.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the solution. I think Magento is just abled to load `navigation.phtml` one time. If we have two extensions what manipulate the account navigation, installed on the same system, will both be loaded by magento? If yes, does magento create two navigations?

Comment: Sure Magento is just able to load `navigation.phtml` one time, so put `$this->addLink("Some Name",...` line in `navigation.phtml` **which is loaded by extension (I mean which is loaded by Magento)**. Main thing here is to add link, and this line will add one while called by `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` block instance.

Comment: Thank you so far. I want the extension for every theme, so I should put the file to `app/design/frontend/base/default/...` but here the file already exists. What is the way to go?

Comment: For creating extension, you can override `navigation.phtml`, that you can find in `<customer_account>` tag from `customer.xml`. Then use `$this->addLink("Some Name",...` line to add new link